# Partial derivative of tensor with respect to tensor

Tags: derivatives, tensor-products, tensors

My question is related to continuum mechanics, taking partial derivative of tensor with respect to tensor.

$$\mathbf{\sigma} = \lambda \hspace{1pt} tr(\mathbf{\epsilon})+ 2\mu\mathbf{\epsilon}$$

Where, $\mathbf{\sigma,\epsilon}$ are second order tensors, $tr(\mathbf{\epsilon})$ is trace of the tensor.

I want to find

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{\sigma}}{\partial\mathbf{\epsilon}}$$

I start like this:

$$ \mathbb{C_{ijmn}}=\frac{\partial {\sigma_{ij}}}{\partial{\epsilon_{mn}}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_{mn}} \big(\lambda\delta_{ij}\epsilon_{kk} + 2\mu\epsilon_{ij} \big)$$

$$=\lambda\delta_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_{mn}}\epsilon_{kk} + 2\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_{mn}}\epsilon_{ij}$$

$$=\lambda\delta_{ij}\delta_{km}\delta_{kn} + 2\mu\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}$$

$$=\lambda\delta_{ij}\delta_{mn}+2\mu\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your derivation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the result is wrong. To show it recall that the stiffness tensor has minor symmetries due the symmetry of both stress and deformation tensors (see e.g. [[1]](http://web.mit.edu/16.20/homepage/3_Constitutive/Constitutive_files/module_3_with_solutions.pdf))). According to your results, e.g. $C_{1212}\neq C_{1221}$ which shows that the tensor **$C$** is not symmetric.

To derive the correct result we have to take into account that:

$$
\frac{\partial \epsilon_{ij}}{\partial \epsilon_{kl}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}\right)=I_{ijkl}
$$

where $I_{ijkl}$ is known as the fourth-order symmetric identity tensor (see e.g. [[2]](https://youtu.be/22f3ske1-e4?list=PL6f9zUtPSkfhAQyJ4GP1O-u4JKokNq4cU&t=1127)).

P.S. Don't forget to multiply the first component of the rhs of the first equation by the second-order identity tensor, otherwise you are adding a scalar with a second-order tensor.